# OpenGL two different  3d rendering picture control on single MFC dialog not working

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc, render

I am making an application using VC++ MFC where i have two different opengl windows. I have followed the tutorial of [enter link description here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm)

I am able to success using one picture control where opengl window shows correct rendering but if i create two different object of that control then one window does not show anything.

To explain more here is the code

m_WinGL and m_WinGL2 are two different object of the customized class inside the initDialog.

```
// Get size and position of the template textfield we created before in the dialog editor
CRect rect;
GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_GL)->GetWindowRect(rect);
ScreenToClient(rect);// Convert screen coordinates to client coordinates

m_WinGL.oglCreate(rect, this);// Create OpenGL Control window
m_WinGL.m_unpTimer = m_WinGL.SetTimer(1, 1, 0);// Setup the OpenGL Window's timer to render


GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_GL2)->GetWindowRect(rect);
ScreenToClient(rect);// Convert screen coordinates to client coordinates

m_WinGL2.oglCreate(rect, this,L"X");// Create OpenGL Control window
m_WinGL2.m_unpTimer = m_WinGL2.SetTimer(1, 1, 0);// Setup the OpenGL Window's timer to render
```

here is the class of customize control

header file

```
#pragma once
#include "afxwin.h"

#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>

class COpenGLControl : public CWnd
{
    public:
        /******************/
        /* Public Members */
        /******************/
        UINT_PTR m_unpTimer;
        // View information variables
        float    m_fLastX;
        float    m_fLastY;
        float    m_fPosX;
        float    m_fPosY;
        float    m_fZoom;
        float    m_fRotX;
        float    m_fRotY;
        bool     m_bIsMaximized;

    private:
        /*******************/
        /* Private Members */
        /*******************/
        // Window information
        CWnd  *hWnd;
        HDC   hdc;          
        HGLRC hrc;          
        int   m_nPixelFormat;
        CRect m_rect;
        CRect m_oldWindow;
        CRect m_originalRect;

    public:
        COpenGLControl(void);
        virtual ~COpenGLControl(void);

        void oglCreate(CRect rect, CWnd *parent,CString strWindowName=L"OpenGl");
        void oglInitialize(void);
        void oglDrawScene(void);

        // Added message classes:
        afx_msg void OnPaint();
        afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
        afx_msg void OnDraw(CDC *pDC);
        afx_msg int  OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
        afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent);
        afx_msg void OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);

        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

cpp file

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "OpenGLControl.h"

    COpenGLControl::COpenGLControl(void)
    {
        m_fPosX = 0.0f;     // X position of model in camera view
        m_fPosY = 0.0f;     // Y position of model in camera view
        m_fZoom = 10.0f;    // Zoom on model in camera view
        m_fRotX = 0.0f;     // Rotation on model in camera view
        m_fRotY = 0.0f;     // Rotation on model in camera view
        m_bIsMaximized = false;
    }

    COpenGLControl::~COpenGLControl(void)
    {
    }

    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(COpenGLControl, CWnd)
        ON_WM_PAINT()
        ON_WM_SIZE()
        ON_WM_CREATE()
        ON_WM_TIMER()
        ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

    void COpenGLControl::OnPaint()
    {
        //CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
        ValidateRect(NULL);
    }

    void COpenGLControl::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
    {
        CWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

        if (0 >= cx || 0 >= cy || nType == SIZE_MINIMIZED) return;

        // Map the OpenGL coordinates.
        glViewport(0, 0, cx, cy);

        // Projection view
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

        glLoadIdentity();

        // Set our current view perspective
        gluPerspective(35.0f, (float)cx / (float)cy, 0.01f, 2000.0f);

        // Model view
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        switch (nType)
        {
            // If window resize token is "maximize"
            case SIZE_MAXIMIZED:
            {
                // Get the current window rect
                GetWindowRect(m_rect);

                // Move the window accordingly
                MoveWindow(6, 6, cx - 14, cy - 14);

                // Get the new window rect
                GetWindowRect(m_rect);

                // Store our old window as the new rect
                m_oldWindow = m_rect;

                break;
            }

            // If window resize token is "restore"
            case SIZE_RESTORED:
            {
                // If the window is currently maximized
                if (m_bIsMaximized)
                {
                    // Get the current window rect
                    GetWindowRect(m_rect);

                    // Move the window accordingly (to our stored old window)
                    MoveWindow(m_oldWindow.left, m_oldWindow.top - 18, m_originalRect.Width() - 4, m_originalRect.Height() - 4);

                    // Get the new window rect
                    GetWindowRect(m_rect);

                    // Store our old window as the new rect
                    m_oldWindow = m_rect;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int COpenGLControl::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
    {
        if (CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1) return -1;

        oglInitialize();

        return 0;
    }

    void COpenGLControl::OnDraw(CDC *pDC)
    {
        // If the current view is perspective...
        glLoadIdentity();

        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -m_fZoom);
        glTranslatef(m_fPosX, m_fPosY, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(m_fRotX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(m_fRotY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    void COpenGLControl::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
    {
        switch (nIDEvent)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                // Clear color and depth buffer bits
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

                // Draw OpenGL scene
                oglDrawScene();

                // Swap buffers
                SwapBuffers(hdc);

                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
        }

        CWnd::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
    }

    void COpenGLControl::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
    {
        int diffX = (int)(point.x - m_fLastX);
        int diffY = (int)(point.y - m_fLastY);
        m_fLastX  = (float)point.x;
        m_fLastY  = (float)point.y;

        // Left mouse button
        if (nFlags & MK_LBUTTON)
        {
            m_fRotX += (float)0.5f * diffY;

            if ((m_fRotX > 360.0f) || (m_fRotX < -360.0f))
            {
                m_fRotX = 0.0f;
            }

            m_fRotY += (float)0.5f * diffX;

            if ((m_fRotY > 360.0f) || (m_fRotY < -360.0f))
            {
                m_fRotY = 0.0f;
            }
        }

        // Right mouse button
        else if (nFlags & MK_RBUTTON)
        {
            m_fZoom -= (float)0.1f * diffY;
        }

        // Middle mouse button
        else if (nFlags & MK_MBUTTON)
        {
            m_fPosX += (float)0.05f * diffX;
            m_fPosY -= (float)0.05f * diffY;
        }

        OnDraw(NULL);

        CWnd::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
    }

    void COpenGLControl::oglCreate(CRect rect, CWnd *parent,CString strWindowName)
    {
        CString className = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC, NULL, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH), NULL);

        CreateEx(0, className,strWindowName, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, rect, parent, 0);

        // Set initial variables' values
        m_oldWindow    = rect;
        m_originalRect = rect;

        hWnd = parent;
    }

    void COpenGLControl::oglInitialize(void)
    {
        // Initial Setup:
        //
        static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
        {
            sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
            1,
            PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
            PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
            32, // bit depth
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            16, // z-buffer depth
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        };

        // Get device context only once.
        hdc = GetDC()->m_hDC;

        // Pixel format.
        m_nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
        SetPixelFormat(hdc, m_nPixelFormat, &pfd);

        // Create the OpenGL Rendering Context.
        hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
        wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);

        // Basic Setup:
        //
        // Set color to use when clearing the background.
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);

        // Turn on backface culling
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);

        // Turn on depth testing
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

        // Send draw request
        OnDraw(NULL);
    }

    void COpenGLControl::oglDrawScene(void)
    {
        // Wireframe Mode
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                // Front Side
                glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

                // Back Side
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

                // Top Side
                glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);

                // Bottom Side
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

                // Right Side
                glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);

                // Left Side
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
                glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL is a thread global context state machine. That means, that you must switch the OpenGL context of the current thread to the right window so that drawing commands end up where you want them.

In every member function in which you make OpenGL calls put at the beginning

```
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
```

and before you leave the function (i.e. at the end, or before a return)

```
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
```

BTW: You can use a single OpenGL context for any number of windows, as long as they share the same visual properties, i.e. if you called `SetPixelFormatDescriptor` with the same PFD for each window you want the context to use with.

Last but not least, all of the code found in `OnSize` and all of the "Basic Setup" found in `onInitialize` should be put into the drawing code. Your `OnDraw` is not very useful either.