# How to choose the right buffer to draw and stop it from swapping continuously

Tags: performance, opengl, drawing, buffer, cpu-usage

**Please tell me if the question's vogue, I need the answe as soon as possible**

for more information about the problem you can refer to this. I just didn't understand how to manage buffers properly.

[A red rectangle drawn on 2D texture disappears right after being drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492396/a-red-rectangle-drawn-on-2d-texture-disappears-right-after-being-drawn)

Being in the last stages of customizing the class [COpenGLControl](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm):
I have created two instances of the class in my MFC Dialog:
[image]
whenever the extent of zoom is changed in the bigger window, it is drawn as a red rectangle on the smaller window. which is always in full extent mode. In order to stablish such a relation between two instances, I have used the concept of user defined messages and send the message to the parent of the class.

**The main trouble**
based on the information above:

1- when I pan in the bigger window (mean I cause the user defined message be sent rapidly and `m_oglWindow2.DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()` be called rapidly I see a track of red rectangles shown but immediately disappeared in the smaller window

2- CPU-usage immediately get's high when panning from 3% to 25%

3- In other navigation tasks liked `Fixed zoom in`,`Fixed zoom out`,`Pan` and etc a red rectangle flashes and then immediately disappears, I mean it seems that the red rectangle is there just when the control is in the function `m_oglWindow2.DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()` but I want the rectangle be there until the next call off `m_oglWindow2.DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()`

4- making calls to `glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK)` and `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` causes the texture in the smaller window to get off and on even if the mouse is idle

I know the problem is most because of the lines `glClear`, `glDrawBuffer`, `SwapBuffers` in the following codes. But I don't know exactly how to solve

```
void COpenGLControl::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc);
switch (nIDEvent)
{
    case 1:
    {
        // Clear color and depth buffer bits
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw OpenGL scene
        oglDrawScene();

        // Swap buffers
        SwapBuffers(hdc);

        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}

CWnd::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}  

void COpenGLControl::DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()
{
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
//glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);
//glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT|GL_CURRENT_BIT);
glDisable(target);
glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
   glVertex2f(RectangleToDraw.at(0),RectangleToDraw.at(1));
   glVertex2f(RectangleToDraw.at(0),RectangleToDraw.at(3));
   glVertex2f(RectangleToDraw.at(2),RectangleToDraw.at(3));
   glVertex2f(RectangleToDraw.at(2),RectangleToDraw.at(1));
glEnd();
glPopAttrib();
SwapBuffers(hdc);
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}  

void COpenGLControl::OnDraw(CDC *pDC)
{
// TODO: Camera controls
wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(m_fPosX, m_fPosY, 0.0f);
glScalef(m_fZoom,m_fZoom,1.0);
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

Remember:

`OnDraw` function is just called twice in the smaller window first when initializing the window and second when calling `m_oglWindow2.ZoomToFullExtent()` and then for each call of `OnDraw` in the bigger window, there's a call to the `DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()` in the smaller one but this function `DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()` is never called in the bigger window

It'll be favor of you if:

- you correct my code
- introduce me an excellent tutorial on how to use buffers in multiple
  drawings that can not be done in a single function or a single thread (An excellent tutorial about buffers eg.color buffers and etc in opengl

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

*I just added explanations below to provide further information about how's the class is working if it's needed. If you think it's bothering viewers just edit it to remove which of the parts that you feel is not required. But please do help me.*

the oglInitialize sets initial parameters for the scene:

```
void COpenGLControl::oglInitialize(void)
{
// Initial Setup:
//
static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
    32, // bit depth
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    24, // z-buffer depth
    8,0,PFD_MAIN_PLANE, 0, 0, 0, 0,
};

// Get device context only once.
hdc = GetDC()->m_hDC;
// Pixel format.
m_nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
SetPixelFormat(hdc, m_nPixelFormat, &pfd);
// Create the OpenGL Rendering Context.
hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
// Basic Setup:
//
// Set color to use when clearing the background.
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
// Turn on backface culling
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
// Turn on depth testing
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
// Send draw request
OnDraw(NULL);
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

example of a navigation task:

**PAN:**

```
void COpenGLControl::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
if (WantToPan)
{
    if (m_fLastX < 0.0f && m_fLastY < 0.0f)
    {
        m_fLastX = (float)point.x;
        m_fLastY = (float)point.y;
    }
    int diffX = (int)(point.x - m_fLastX);
    int diffY = (int)(point.y - m_fLastY);
    m_fLastX = (float)point.x;
    m_fLastY = (float)point.y;
    if (nFlags & MK_MBUTTON)
    {
        m_fPosX += (float)0.05f*m_fZoomInverse*diffX;
        m_fPosY -= (float)0.05f*m_fZoomInverse*diffY;
    }
    if (WantToSetViewRectangle)
        setViewRectangle();
    OnDraw(NULL);
}
CWnd::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

**the most important part:**   before calling `OnDraw` in each of the navigation functions if the client-programmer has set `WantToSetViewRectangle` as true means that he wants the view rectangle for the window to be calculated and calls `setViewRectangle()` which is as follows. It sends a message to the parent in case of an update for `ViewRectangle`:

```
void COpenGLControl::setViewRectangle()
{
CWnd *pParentOfClass = CWnd::GetParent();
ViewRectangle.at(0) = -m_fPosX - oglWindowWidth*m_fZoomInverse/2;
ViewRectangle.at(1) = -m_fPosY - oglWindowHeight*m_fZoomInverse/2;
ViewRectangle.at(2) = -m_fPosX + oglWindowWidth*m_fZoomInverse/2;
ViewRectangle.at(3) = -m_fPosY + oglWindowHeight*m_fZoomInverse/2;
bool is_equal = ViewRectangle == LastViewRectangle;
if (!is_equal)
    pParentOfClass ->SendMessage(WM_RECTANGLECHANGED,0,0);
LastViewRectangle.at(0) = ViewRectangle.at(0);
LastViewRectangle.at(1) = ViewRectangle.at(1);
LastViewRectangle.at(2) = ViewRectangle.at(2);
LastViewRectangle.at(3) = ViewRectangle.at(3);
}
```

this is how we use the class in the client code:

**MyOpenGLTestDlg.h**

two instances of class:

```
COpenGLControl m_oglWindow;
COpenGLControl m_oglWindow2;
```

**MyOpenGLTestDlg.cpp**

apply texture on the windows and set both of them to full extent in the `OnInitDlg`

```
    m_oglWindow.pImage = m_files.pRasterData;
    m_oglWindow.setImageWidthHeightType(m_files.RasterXSize,m_files.RasterYSize,m_files.eType);
    m_oglWindow.m_unpTimer = m_oglWindow.SetTimer(1, 1, 0);  

    m_oglWindow2.pImage = m_files.pRasterData;
    m_oglWindow2.setImageWidthHeightType(m_files.RasterXSize,m_files.RasterYSize,m_files.eType);
    m_oglWindow2.m_unpTimer = m_oglWindow2.SetTimer(1, 20, 0);  
    m_oglWindow2.ZoomToFullExtent();
    m_oglWindow.ZoomToFullExtent();
```

want pan, zoomtool and setViewRectangle be active for the bigger window but not for the smaller one:

```
m_oglWindow.WantToPan = true;
m_oglWindow.WantToUseZoomTool = true;
m_oglWindow.WantToSetViewRectangle = true;
```

handling the user-defined message in the parent. exchange the `ViewRectangle` data to the smaller window and draw the red rectangle:

```
LRESULT CMyOpenGLTestDlg::OnRectangleChanged(WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
m_oglWindow2.RectangleToDraw = m_oglWindow.ViewRectangle;
m_oglWindow2.DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture();
return 0;
}
```

Here's [the full customized class](http://www.4shared.com/rar/SzVIlQxP/MyOpenGLTest.html) if you're interested in downloading it and fix my problem.

Comment: Is there any way you could post a little less code to go through?

Comment: well I said I'm sure the main trouble is in the code posted under the horizontal line. I just added them to say that for example when `OnDraw` is called and etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're drawing on a timer and when your application receives a `WM_PAINT` message. MFC invokes your `OnDraw (...)` callback when it needs to repaint the window, you should move **ALL** of your drawing functionality into `OnDraw (...)` and call `OnDraw (...)` from your timer function.

```
void COpenGLControl::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
  switch (nIDEvent)
  {
    case 1:
    {
      OnDraw (NULL);
      break;
    }

    default:
      break;
  }

  CWnd::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}

void COpenGLControl::OnDraw(CDC *pDC)
{
  // TODO: Camera controls
  wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc);

  // Clear color and depth buffer bits
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glLoadIdentity ();
  gluLookAt      (0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0);
  glTranslatef   (m_fPosX, m_fPosY, 0.0f);
  glScalef       (m_fZoom,m_fZoom,1.0);

  // Draw OpenGL scene
  oglDrawScene();

  // Swap buffers
  SwapBuffers(hdc);

  wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}

void COpenGLControl::DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()
{
  glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT|GL_CURRENT_BIT);
  glDisable(target);
  glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(RectangleToDraw.at(0),RectangleToDraw.at(1));
    glVertex2f(RectangleToDraw.at(0),RectangleToDraw.at(3));
    glVertex2f(RectangleToDraw.at(2),RectangleToDraw.at(3));
    glVertex2f(RectangleToDraw.at(2),RectangleToDraw.at(1));
  glEnd();
  glPopAttrib();
}
```

And only ever make calls to `wglMakeCurrent (...)` within `OnDraw (...)`. This function is really meant for situations where you're rendering into multiple render contexts, or drawing using multiple threads.

Comment: have you noticed that OnDraw is not automatically runned by MFC. Because it's not included in the MESSAGE_MAP and I've just created it manually also the code for WM_PAINT IS {ValidateRect(NULL)}

Comment: also you mean there's no need to take the `DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()` into the OnTimer?  the `DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()` is called through a user defined handler in the parent

Comment: Draw everything all at once, is what I'm saying here. Clear the color/depth buffer { draw X, draw Y, draw Z } swap buffers. If you have to call multiple functions to draw everything you want, they should all happen inbetween the time you cleared the buffers and swapped them in `OnDraw (...)` and nothing but `OnDraw (...)` should be swapping buffers, or calling `wglMakeCurrent (...)`

Comment: but you haven't made `DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()` into the OnDraw and also OnDraw is not a drawing function it just makes some transfers on the model

Comment: If you have a user-defined handler in the parent window, make it re-draw everything. Change some state and make it call your control's OnDraw (...) function. You cannot draw things partially in a double buffered system, you basically have to draw everything and ***THEN*** swap buffers.

Comment: well it's the thing that I would like to say don't you think it is better to call the both `oglDrawScene` and `DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()` in the OnTimer function and then call `OnTimer` everytime from the userdefined message handler in the parent and then leave the `OnDraw` as it was?

Comment: I'll delete and mark the parts that helped me alot but last thing is about your point for `wglMakeCurrent` I have two ogl windows I learned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227586/opengl-two-different-3d-rendering-picture-control-on-single-mfc-dialog-not-work) that I should use this in every function that has used commands with gl prefix.

Comment: Right, `wglMakeCurrent (...)` is very important to call when you have two controls. But you really only need to call it when you start/finish rendering one, and not within the little functions that only do one or two things (like draw a rectangle over the texture). You also should only be swapping buffers in one location, at the very end of all of your drawing commands.

Comment: OK that's it. It works perfectly.thanks for your attention. I call both `oglDrawScene` and `DrawRectangleOnTopOfTextures` in `OnTimer` and call the `OnTimer` within the message handler. As you said **You cannot draw things partially in a double buffered system, you basically have to draw everything and THEN swap buffers**